# Can you use Amazon S3 via Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Due to the lack of clientaccesspolicy.xml, there appears to be problems with using Amazon S3 via Flex. Are there any work arounds?

**Edit:** Both of the below answers are great and work, I've upvoted both (I'm not going to assign an answer to the question as they both work):

[Can you use Amazon S3 via Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186768/can-you-use-amazon-s3-via-flex#186889)

[Can you use Amazon S3 via Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186768/can-you-use-amazon-s3-via-flex#194362)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can CNAME a subdomain you control at Amazon S3 (to a bucket with the name of the subdomain), like so:

http://s3.ceejayoz.com/ (goes to my 's3.ceejayoz.com' bucket)

Uploading your own clientaccesspolicy.xml file to the root of that bucket (and setting the permissions to be globally viewable) should do the trick, if I'm understanding your question correctly, as it will be accessible at http://s3.ceejayoz.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml.

More information in the S3 docs: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/index.html?VirtualHosting.html

**edit:** From looking at that, you could also use the "Example Virtual Hosted Style Method" without a CNAME: http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/clientaccesspolicy.xml

Comment: I believe you mean crossdomain.xml. clientaccesspolicy.xml is for Silverlight.

Comment: I just copied the file he said he needed from the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can find an ActionScript 3 library for connecting to S3 at:

http://code.google.com/p/as3awss3lib/

with more information at:

http://weblogs.macromedia.com/cantrell/archives/2007/05/actionscript_li.html

You can look at an example of the API in use by checking out the S3E AIR app at:

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/air/sample_apps/S3E.air

and you can grab the source code from:

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/air/sample_apps/S3E.zip

hope that helps...

mike chambers

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a working Rails - Flex - S3 example then have a look at this rails project: http://github.com/GreenAsJade/s3-swf-upload-plugin

Its documented and works out of the box. You can even reverse engineer the Flex logic.