# Is S3 usable in Flex through a browser?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, browser, amazon-s3

I am aware that Amazon S3 is usable in Flex via an AIR application ( [Can you use Amazon S3 via Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186768/can-you-use-amazon-s3-via-flex) ) but was curious if the same applied to a browser ( swf ) compilation of Flex source.

At http://code.google.com/p/as3awss3lib/ it states that:

"It only works in Apollo because of restrictions in the
browser player."  (Apollo is the code name for what is now called AIR
- the desktop runtime.)

Does anyone have any experience with this and can confirm otherwise?

Thank you.

EDIT: No one has tried this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Flash Player running in the browser does not have access to the response headers. Amazon S3 is probably sending important informations in response headers.
This was discussed before:

[Access HTTP response headers in for flash.net.URLLoader object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185761/access-http-response-headers-in-for-flash-net-urlloader-object)

You could try using 3rd party library called as3httpclientlib, code examples at http://code.google.com/p/as3httpclientlib/wiki/Examples