# Upload from Flex/flash player in the browser to S3

Tags: apache-flex, amazon-s3

I've been messing with this all day and am about to throw myself out of the window. OK, not really.

I want to upload directly to an S3 bucket.
I know this can be done in AIR, but could someone advise me whether it is actually possible in flex in the browser, or will I have to use some code server side to get this going?

Any pointers much much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Flex (ui) ---> Java (server side) --->  **[jets3t](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)** (connect to Amazon S3 and create bucket, upload, download etc.) You  can customize **[jets3t](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)** for your needs (customize **[Cockpit](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/applications/applications.html#cockpit)** application of **[jets3t](http://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)**'s)

Additional ; 
**[Amazon S3 POST Example in Flash](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1092)** 
**[Can you use Amazon S3 via Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186768/can-you-use-amazon-s3-via-flex#186889)**